# How to use html input with lightning-web-components

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to make a basic form using standard html inputs that only allow numbers. The input has an `onkeyup` event handler that filters the value and sets an internal variable if it is numeric characters.

The problem is the input is not respecting the `value` I am setting and displays all keys entered.

Input:

```
<label>
    <span class="required">Site ID: {siteId}</span>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" onkeyup={handleSiteIdChange} value={siteId}/>
</label>
```

handler:

```
@track siteId = '';

handleSiteIdChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        this.siteId = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

Before I get suggestions to use `lightning-input` I am using standard `inputs` because I am unable to override the styling on `lightning-input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by using `this.template.querySelector`

```html
<label>
    <span class="required">Site ID:</span>
    <input data-id="site-id" type="text" class="text-input" oninput={handleSiteIdChange}/>
</label>
```

```js
handleSiteIdChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="site-id"]`).value = value;
        this.siteId = value;
    } else {
        this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="site-id"]`).value = this.siteId;
    }
}
```